# Read Emails of a shared mailbox from different user using Java mail API

Tags: jakarta-mail

I have a Microsoft user account in which mailbox is not configured. I want to access the mailbox of another user account which has a shared folder (inbox). How can it be done using Java mail API?

I have seen examples posted before, but in my case, I don't have a mailbox configured for my user account.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to access a mailbox in another user account on an Exchange server?  Can you login to the Exchange server?  You may need to login to the server using the alias name for the shared mailbox, as described in [this article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8c8b4605-efae-49eb-a118-54aa418de6c2/access-shared-mailbox-via-imap-on-exchange-2010?forum=exchangesvrgenerallegacy).

Comment: I dont have login to mail exhange server as for my user account, mailbox is not configured. But Admin has delegated me to access the mailbox of another user account. How should I connect to other mailbox in this case using java api.

Comment: Did you read the article I referenced above?  I'm not an Exchange expert, but my understanding is that you need the alias name for the mailbox, which you can get from your Exchange administrator.